# The SubView's background is lost

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

My application's structure is as follow:

- UITabViewController:

  - First UIViewController:

    - UIPageViewController:

      ```
      - Page1: UIViewController:

                  - UIView: contains Some UILabels, 1 UIButton

      - Page2: UIViewController:

                  - UIView: contains Some UILabels, 1 UIButton
      ```
  - Second UIViewController:

The UIView I added programmatically in the UIViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    SessionView* b = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SessionView" owner:self options:nil] lastObject];
    CGRect frame = b.frame;

    b.frame = CGRectMake(0, 88, frame.size.width, frame.size.height);

    [self.view addSubview:b];
}
```

The weird thing is the UIView appears without its background color. And the button cannot be tapped.

[image: missing background]

I upload the source code [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/eyogupm952fmten/vovan.zip?dl=0) just in case you want to check.

I am working on iOS8, XCode6, iPad

Thanks a lot.

Comment: In your project, when debugging the view hierarchy you can see that the issue is not the background color. The SessionView has a height of 0, which also explains why you can't tap the button. The event can't reach it. I don't get quite why you set all this up in this specific way (instantiating from storyboard, then loading a view from xib). I will try to have a closer look this evening.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
  [mainview bringSubviewToFront:subview];
```

Comment: this is the first thing coming up in my mind, but it doesn't help.

Comment: here are problem with calling of action ,create action of button and then call it for view.

Comment: u are calling in reverse way

Comment: It's a normal way. You can implement the "touch up inside" of UIButton in a View that contains this button.

Answer (score 0):

[image: image is provided below]

tick mark a subview clip...............

Comment: By default, the value "clip Subviews" is not selected. When I enable this value, my UIView disappear. You can download my source code, and try, you will see.